# Showing last command in IDLE

Tags: python

I am using IDLE 3 in windows . My question is simply , is there any way we can get the last thing entered by pressing the up arrow key ( like in case of ipython ) .

It is very problematic to copy the last command and again to paste it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to go up

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to go down.

If you don't like this binding, you could remap it:

```
Options -> Configure IDLE -> Keys
```

Answer (score 2):

Check IDLE key preferences. For Mac it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. look for history-previous key mapping